# How do I permanently disable yaml files on puppet?

Tags: puppet

It has never happened before, but all of a sudden my server keeps running out of space because of these puppet reports.
Can  reports=none inside the puppet.conf file, auto disable the generation of .yaml report files? Or is there a better way of doing it?
Will we ever need these .yaml files and do they affect anything if I delete them all?

Comment: puppet enterprise or open-source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet has fairly good online documentation, including for historic versions of the software.  You can find a good overview of the reporting feature here: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/reporting.html.  A bit more detail is provided in [the relevant section of the manual proper](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/reporting_about.html), and the configuration reference provides [some detail on the relevant configuration settings](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/configuration.html#report).

Some of the configurable aspects of reporting are:

- whether agents send reports [the `report` parameter in the `[agent]` section of the config file].  This is configured on a per-agent basis.  By default, they do send reports.
- what the master does with the reports it receives [the `reports` parameter in the `[master]` section of the config file].  The default is to use (only) the `store` report handler, which dumps them to YAML files in the configured report directory.

> Can reports=none inside the puppet.conf file, auto disable the generation of .yaml report files?

No '`none`' handler is documented, but you can write and plug in custom report handlers, as described in the docs.  A `none` handler ought to be trivial to write, but see below.

> Or is there a better way of doing it?

I'd recommend configuring your agents to not send reports in the first place.  That should be less work for all involved, human and machine.  Do that by setting `report = false` (note: singlular "report") in the `[agent]` section of each agent's Puppet configuration file.  You may need to restart the agents after.

> Will we ever need these .yaml files and do they affect anything if I delete all of them?

They are for your benefit.  If you have no use for them, then you can safely delete them.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the detailed response as usual. I tried report = false after reading the documents from puppetlabs, but I put it inside the master not agents. Probably that's why it wasn't working. I have 90+ agents, so probably setting the cron job to delete it every day would be quicker than changing the config file on each agent.

Comment: @James, I had supposed that your agents' `puppet.conf` files were under Puppet management, which is common.  If that were the case (or if you choose to *make* it the case), then at least updating the config files would be pretty simple.